# Looping through '{en:}hello{nl:}hoi' with preg_match

Tags: php, regex, translation, preg-match

I'm working on a translation function that should work like this: _('{en:}hello{nl:}hoi')
But I'm having trouble with writing a correct regular expression. So far I have this code:

```
preg_match('/\{([a-zA-Z_]{2,4}):\}(.*)/', $translate, $matches);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches) / 2; $i + 2)
{
    $return .= '<!--:' . $matches[$i] . '-->' . $matches[$i + 1] . '<!--:-->';
}
```

But my matches array holds this:

```
array
  0 => string '{en:}hello{nl:}hoi' (length=23)
  1 => string 'en' (length=2)
  2 => string 'hello{nl:}hoi' (length=18)
```

Any ideas for a proper regex? Or even a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what the function should return, so the following function will return an associative array with the language as keys and the text as values:

```
function _($translate)
{
    $result = array();
    if (preg_match_all('/\{(.+?):\}([^{]+)/', $translate, $matches))
    {
        for ($i = 0, $len = count($matches[0]); $i < $len; ++$i)
        {
            $result[$matches[1][$i]] = $matches[2][$i];
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Example:

```
print_r(_('{en:}hello{nl:}hoi'));
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [en] => hello
    [nl] => hoi
)
```

Comment: You can replace `.+` with `[a-zA-Z_]{2,4}` if that more accurately reflects the string containing the language code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to change (.*) so that it doesn't match the character `{`:

```
/\{([a-zA-Z_]{2,4}):\}([^{]*)/
```